# while loop inside a coroutine in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts. The first script gets called in the beginning as follows:
Script1.cs

```
private Script2 script2;

void Start () {
        script2= (Script2) GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof (Script2));
        StartCoroutine("CallTrigger");
    }

IEnumerator CallTrigger() {
        while(script2.hasTriggered == true){
         Debug.Log("Success");
         script2.hasTriggered = false;
        }
    yield return 0;
}
```

And my script 2 is as follows:

```
public bool hasTriggered = false;
```

Since my 1st script gets called first, I want the CallTrigger() function to wait till the bool in script2 is set to true. Unfortunately while() is not the right way I suppose since it is not working for me. I know the best way is to use Update() but I am using multiple instances of this script from which only some get called in the beginning.

So how do I make my CallTrigger await till the hasTriggered in script2 is set to true?

Comment: "not working" is not a valid problem description. What exactly is "not working" ...

Comment: the while() loop is not working. I feel it runs only one time. If the condition is false, it just exits.

Comment: Well, the condition is `while (script2.hasTriggered == true)` and inside the loop's body you are setting `script2.hasTriggered = false`. Why whould you expect the loop to continue, as the condition is obviously not fulfilled anymore?

Comment: That is my question, how do I make the loop await till the condition is set to true?

Comment: It must already be true, otherwise it won't enter the loop ...

Comment: Or is `script2.hastriggered` initially set to `false` and you want to wait until it becomes `true`? Then your condition has to be `while (script2.hasTriggered == false)`

Comment: And I don't mean to be rude, but you seem to be lacking very basic programming skills. You should perhaps read some basic tutorials first. Stackoverflow is not a site to teach programming ...

Comment: @derpirscher I don't think you understood my question in first hand or maybe I was not able to explain properly, but derHugo has provided the solution I wanted :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want the CallTrigger() function to wait till the bool in script2 is set to true

You can simply use [`WaitUntil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html)

```
IEnumerator CallTrigger() 
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => script2.hasTriggered);

    Debug.Log("Success");
}
```

which basically equals doing something like

```
IEnumerator CallTrigger() 
{
    // As long as the flag is NOT set
    while(!script2.hasTriggered)
    {
        // wait a frame
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("Success");
}
```

---

You could also btw directly make it

```
// Yes, if Start returns IEnumerator Unity automatcally runs it as a coroutine
IEnumerator Start()
{
    // Rather use the generic versions
    script2 = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Script2>();

    yield return new WaitUntil(()=> script2.hasTriggered);

    Debug.Log("Success");
}
```

Comment: Exactly how I wanted! Thank you :)

Comment: Also, just to add a point, shouldn't it be yield return new WaitUntil?

Comment: @Saif it should yes ;)